# Update parameter on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating 2 modules, 1) price list, 2) discount list. These two modules share a table in the database called "relclili" in it will store the customer id called "CustomerCustomer", the id of the price list "ListP" and the id of the discount list " ". When the customer is added to a list of discounts or prices then the record is created the relclili, but if the customer is added to a price list and then added to a discount then one should not create a new record but modify The record that was created when the customer was added to the price list

I Tried to make it work but it shows me an error in the .js file
this is the error I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `CodCliente' for true:TrueClass):
    1: $("#myclientadder_<%= @relclili.CodCliente %>").modal('hide');
    2: 
    3: $("#container_relclilis").prepend('<%= j render @relclili %>'); //Prepend before append
    4: $("#relclili_<%= @relclili.id %>").hide().fadeIn(1000);
  app/views/relclilis/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_relclilis_create_js_erb___1051626349__1016832438'
```

this is my create action:

```
def create
    if Relclili.exists?(CodCliente: relclili_params[:CodCliente])
      @relclili =  (Relclili.find_by(CodCliente: relclili_params[:CodCliente]).first.update(ListaP: relclili_params[:ListaP]))
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @relclili, notice: 'Relclili was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @relclili }
        format.js {flash.now[:notice] = 'El cliente se ha agregado de forma exitosa.'} #ajax
      end

    else
      @relclili = Relclili.new(relclili_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @relclili.save
          format.html { redirect_to @relclili, notice: 'Relclili was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @relclili }
          format.js {flash.now[:notice] = 'El cliente se ha agregado de forma exitosa.'} #ajax

        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @relclili.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.js {flash.now[:alert] = 'Error al agregar el cliente.'} #ajax

        end
      end
    end
  end
```

this is my create.js.erb

```
$("#myclientadder_<%= @relclili.CodCliente %>").modal('hide');

$("#container_relclilis").prepend('<%= j render @relclili %>'); //Prepend before append
$("#relclili_<%= @relclili.id %>").hide().fadeIn(1000);
$("#cliente_<%= @relclili.CodCliente %>").fadeOut(500, function(){
  $(this).remove();
  $(".child").remove();

});
$("#notice").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'partials/flash' , :locals => { :flash => flash }).html_safe %>");



setTimeout(function(){
  $('#notice').fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $(this).create();
  })
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies here:

```
@relclili =  (Relclili.find_by(CodCliente: relclili_params[:CodCliente]).first.update(ListaP: relclili_params[:ListaP]))
```

Split the above into 2 lines (one to get, and 1 to update):

```
@relclili =  (Relclili.find_by(CodCliente: relclili_params[:CodCliente]).first
@relclili.update(ListaP: relclili_params[:ListaP])) if @relclili.present?
```

The reason why your code fails is because the `update` command does not return the object, but just a boolean saying whether update succeeded or failed. Hence it says `undefined method CodCliente for true:TrueClass)`

Comment: Thank you my friend this solved my issue, thank you so much for the explanation